# Label a slide in a frame

Tags: beamer, cross-referencing, labels, slideshow

Suppose I have a frame in which bullet points are going to be shown one after the other. Is there a way I can attach a label to each \item in the enumeration in such a way that when I reference it later, the reference refers to the slide number that specific \item was uncovered on?

The reason I ask this is that often when creating a presentation, I have a bunch of slides within a frame, and I end up having to add a new slide at the beginning of the frame. When this happens, I have to renumber all the other slides. It would be convenient if I could just have something that allows me to refer to the slide number of a previous item. That way I don't have to renumber everything, especially if things get moved around.

For instance, and I doubt this is how it would actually be (but just so you get the general gist of what I am trying to do), something like

```
\begin{enumerate}
   \item thing1 \label{bullet about thing1}
   \onslide<\ref{bullet about thing1} + 1 - > {\item thing2 }
\end{enumerate}
```

Ideally the solution would work not just for bullet points, but for anything.

Comment: What exactly is the intended use case? From the code fragment you added, I guess you want to access the overlay slide number since you use `\onslide` in order to etepwise uncover your items. Wouldn't `\begin{enumerate} \item thing1 \pause \item thing2 \end{enumerate}` or `\begin{enumerate}[<+->] \item thing1 \item thing2 \end{enumerate}` work for that, as well?

Comment: Can't you just use `\pause` to achieve what you want?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly (but probably I did not), this should be possible with quite a simple setup:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{enumerate}
   \item<1-> Thing 1
   \item<2-> Thing 2 \label<2>{thing2}
   \item<3-> Thing 3
\end{enumerate}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}

Jump to Thing 2: \ref{thing2}.
    
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The last frame should look like this and clicking on the reference should jump to the frame where the second item has just been uncovered:

[image]